# Substring Time And Space Complexity in Python

Tags: python, string, time-complexity, space-complexity

What is the time and space complexity of getting a substring in Python?

I checked online, and I couldn't find this info anywhere. (I was only able to find list slicing time and space complexity which is `O(k)`).

So, I assume that the time complexity is the same for getting a substring from a string.

Is my assumption of its time and space complexity correct?

Comment: Are you talking about finding the substring or just getting the slice by indexing? If it is indexing then yes, it is 0(k), i.e the time taken to copy into a new   string object.

Comment: Was talking about getting a slice/substring. Thanks for the clarification!